# URL wont open file:\C filepath in Java

Tags: java, url, path, uri, filepath

I need to open a filename using a URL(java.net.URL) as below:

> file:/C:/RAdev/Basic/src/test/resources/xml Data/test
>   dir/app-config-seed-data.xml

I've the following java code to read

```
                fileURL = new File(filePath).toURI().toURL();
                is = fileURL.openStream();
```

Since windows can access file:\, even URL should be able to open the same.

Workaround used for now:

```
            public static final String FILE_URL_PREFIX = "file:";
            if (filePath.contains(FILE_URL_PREFIX)) {
                filePath = filePath.replaceAll("file:/", ""); 
                System.out.println("Modified filepath - " + filePath);
            }
            fileURL = new File(filePath).toURI().toURL();
            is = fileURL.openStream();
```

Is the above workaround needed, please let me know if there is another way to reap the benefits of URL accessing. I'm new to URL/URI in java, help is really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: In windows, this would be (note double // after file:)

file://C:/RAdev/Basic/src/test/resources/xml Data/test dir/app-config-seed-data.xml

I don't have a java environment to test.  Are the path rules the same?

Comment: Application servers access filesystem as file:/C. Yes path rules are same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`file:/C:/` is not a valid file url. Try starting your URLs with `file://C:/`.

Additionally, the `File(String)` constructor does not take a URL, it takes a local file path. If you have a URL as a string that you want to parse, use the `URL(String)` constructor:

```
URL fileURL = new URL("file://C:/RAdev/Basic/src/test/resources/xml Data/test dir/app-config-seed-data.xml");
is = fileURL.openStream();
```

Comment: Adding the below implementation on top of your suggestion worked:

URL url = new URL(filePath);
URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), url.getRef());
fileURL = uri.toURL();

is = fileURL.openStream();

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Adding the below implementation on top of Darth Android suggestion worked:

```
URL url = new URL(filePath);
URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), 
    url.getPort(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), 
    url.getRef());
URL fileURL = uri.toURL();
InputStream is = fileURL.openStream();
```